# How can I read Skype's menus on a dark theme?

Tags: 10.04, appearance, skype

If you use skype with the default 10.04 theme you can't read any menu because the font and background colours are too similar.

Comment: I've always just squinted REALLY hard. I'd definitely like to find an answer for this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Click on the skype symbol on the bottom left. Click on *Options*, six entry if you are not able to see it at all.

It will open a new window, on the right there is a combo box labeled "Choose Style", click on it and choose Desktop Setting. Restart Skype.

Comment: Just a nice trick that I have discovered right now by sheer chance. Let's share it here as I believe we are building a very useful Ubuntu knowledge base.

Comment: That's always encouraged!

Comment: i had to overcome that one the hard way :)